# Como fazer o compilador diferenciar em C++ na hora da chamada o construtor para array estático e para ponteiro qualquer?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, template, sobrecarga

Uso Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Versão 16.11.5.

Assuma `int a[3]` (certamente empilhado), `int *p` (possivelmente apontando para algo deletável na heap) e `struct S` com construtores a seguir abordados.

- Quando implemento somente `S::S( int* )`, ele aceita inicializar `S sp=p , sa=a;`, ou seja, constrói com ambos valores.
- Quando tem somente `template< int al > S::S( int(&)[al] )`, ele aceita `a` e ainda deduz `al=3`, mas não aceita `p`.
- Quando ambos métodos estão disponíveis, tanto `a` quanto `p` são chamados por `S::S( int* )`. Não há sequer aviso de ambiguidade.

Eu estranhei isso.

Vi que quando define um método `void M()` e um `void M() const` os objetos sem qualificadores `const` no tipo chamam o primeiro, já os que têm chamam o segundo, ou seja, priorizam os mais restritos, menos abrangentes. Não aconteceu isso com os construtures, nem com gambiarras.

**É possível fazer a chamada priorizar mais `S::S( int (&)[al] )` do que `S::S( int8 )` de modo que diferencie as chamadas com argumentos `a` e `p` sem depender de especificação de template (seja lá como faz com construtor)?**